# Pulling data from sqlserver at remote to mysql at local at regular interval

Tags: mysql, sql-server, database

I have a database in sql server that sits in remote machine . I need to pull that data into mysql database on my local machine every 15 min.

I am not much of a technical guy. Please could anyone suggest me easy ways on how can i do this.

Comment: How much records do you have to pull every 15 minutes?

Answer (score 1):

you can do in two ways :

1. Manual way : 
   you can use sync tools for database like redgate to sync the data .
2. you can write one windows service which will fetch data from server database and insert all new data into new database every 15 min . you can write windows service in C# using visual studio . you can find some detail of windows service from http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2011/06/creating-windows-service-in-c-or.html .

you can access database from windows services and do some processing on it . you can schedule windows service so that it can execute your script after every 15 min .

Comment: i think redgate is not free .Can you tell what window service i can write .

Comment: @user1896796 , I modified my answer .please check it . tell me if you need any further information about it . redgate is not free but you can find some free tool to sync database from the internet .

Comment: you can't make windows service from eclipse . you have to use visual studio .

Answer (score 0):

You can use Eclipse just fine to write a service/job that would pull data from SQL Server to MySQL.

In Java, you would want to use JDBC to do this.

If you're not a very technical person, my suggestion would be to either learn to do it, or find someone else who knows. What you are requesting is not a simple task. It covers quite a few topics (jobs, scheduling, database connectivity) that you'd need to have some experience with.

You can also check out something like Mule ESB (http://www.mulesoft.org/) which is free. It has some good out of the box functions that can move data from point A to point B.